# What format is expected for data provided to build a Pixi Spritesheet?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I would like to take advantage of `PIXI.Spritesheet` to get some kind of collection of textures or sprites to use in a pixi application.

```
let spritesheetTexture = PIXI.utils.TextureCache["my-spritesheet-image.png"];
let data = ??????
let spritesheet = new PIXI.Spritesheet(spritesheetTexture, data);
```

Unfortunately [the pixi documentation](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Spritesheet.html) gives no indication of what format the `data` parameter needs to be in, besides "object" and "Spritesheet image data". I also cannot find [any examples](http://pixijs.io/examples/) of this class in action.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone still looking for an official answer to this, the typescript defs in the current (Oct., 2020) Pixi.js repository (see [Spritesheet.ts](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/main/packages/spritesheet/src/Spritesheet.ts)) contains the complete schema. These typedefs do not make it into `node_modules` when you import the package, but if you look through the code, it does look like this describes all of the data pixijs looks for when parsing a spritesheet object.

```
export interface ISpritesheetFrameData {
    frame: {
        x: number;
        y: number;
        w: number;
        h: number;
    };
    trimmed?: boolean;
    rotated?: boolean;
    sourceSize?: {
        w: number;
        h: number;
    };
    spriteSourceSize?: {
        x: number;
        y: number;
    };
    anchor?: IPointData;
}

/**
 * Atlas format.
 */
export interface ISpritesheetData {
    frames: Dict<ISpritesheetFrameData>;
    animations?: Dict<string[]>;
    meta: {
        scale: string;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `data` argument should be a JSON-like object listing all frames of a texture atlas (spritesheet) and should look like this:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "image": "atlas.png"
    },
    "frames": {
        "icon_1.png": {
            "frame": {"x":0, "y":0, "w":32, "h":32},
            "sourceSize": {"w": 32, "h": 32}
        },
        "icon_2.png": {
            "frame": {"x":32, "y":0, "w":64, "h":64},
            "sourceSize":{"w": 64, "h": 64}
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

But I don't think you should write that by hand nor use `PIXI.Spritesheet` directly (unless you are doing something more advanced than just display images from a texture atlas). This JSON structure should be exported by a software that packs multiple images to a single texture (e.g. [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker)) and such accompanying JSON file which then should be loaded using PIXI's loader like this:

```
PIXI.loader
    .add('atlas', 'atlas.json')
    .load(onAssetsLoaded);

function onAssetsLoaded() {
    ...
}
```

See also [this example](http://pixijs.io/examples/index.html?s=basics&f=spritesheet.js&title=SpriteSheet%20Animation#/basics/spritesheet.js).